# Solving $a^2x_1x_2+abx_1+abx_2+b^2=a(x_1+x_2)+b$ in terms of $a,b$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

Suppose that $f \colon (\mathbb{R}, +) \to (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$ has the form 
$$f(x) = ax + b$$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Under which conditions on $a$ and $b$ is $f$ operation preserving?

{Answer:} For operation preservation mapping, we seek  $f(x_1) \star_Y f(x_2)=f(x_1 \star_X x_2)$

$f(x_1) \star_Y f(x_2)=f(x_1) \cdot f(x_2)=(ax_1+b) \cdot (ax_2+b)=a^2x_1x_2+abx_1+abx_2+b^2$

$f(x_1 \star_X x_2)=f(x_1 +  x_2)=a(x_1+x_2)+b$

Equating these two equations, we get $a^2x_1x_2+abx_1+abx_2+b^2=a(x_1+x_2)+b$

Can someone please help me in solving this in terms of $a,b$? I can't seem to figure out the algebra for some reason.

Comment: In general, functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ with $f$ differentiable has only non trivial solutions $f(x)=a^x$. Trivial solutions are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the equation needs to hold for *arbitrary* $x_1$ and $x_2$, so you can pick whatever values you like for those that are most convenient.  In particular, choosing $x_1 = -x_2$ leads to the equation $$a^2 x_1^2 = b - b^2$$  However, the only way a non-constant expression, $a^2 x_1^2$, can equal a constant one, $b - b^2$, is if $a = 0$.

So now the equation is reduced to $$b^2 = b$$ which I'm sure you can easily solve.  You can then verify that the definition of $f$ satisfies the laws for the solution(s) you get.